# ASP.NET MVC How does AuthorizeAttribute support checking Roles?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

In my controllers, I have code like `[Authorize(Roles = "Administrators")]` annotated above some actions, and I want to know how `AuthorizeAttribute` uses the Roles parameter (the implementation of the checking mechanism). My goal is to create an extension of this class, called `PrivilegeAttribute` for example, so that I can annotate actions like `[Privilege(Privileges = "read")]`. In this class, I would check if the Role of the user has at least one of the privileges in this custom filter (`read` in this example). I have already created the association between roles and privileges in the code and in the database, and what I want help with is checking whether the role is associated to the privilege.

I tried seeing if that information is there in `HttpContextBase.User.Identity` but I couldn't find it.
Thank you.

Comment: Check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5117782/how-to-extend-authorizeattribute-and-check-the-users-roles. I also found this guide: http://www.diaryofaninja.com/blog/2011/07/24/writing-your-own-custom-aspnet-mvc-authorize-attributes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need your own custom attribute and could live with using someone else attribute, than I would suggest to use the package Thinktecture.IdentityModel.Owin.ResourceAuthorization.Mvc as described here

[Blog Post by Dominick Baier](https://leastprivilege.com/2014/06/24/resourceaction-based-authorization-for-owin-and-mvc-and-web-api/)

and here

[Git Hub Sample Code for the Package](https://github.com/IdentityModel/Thinktecture.IdentityModel/tree/master/samples/OWIN/ResourceAuthorization)

so it basically works like this:
you put an attribute over your action like this:

```
[ResourceAuthorize("View", "Customer")]
```

The first argument is the name of the Action to check, the second one is the name of the attribute.

Then you derive from ResourceAuthorizationManager in your code and override the CheckAccessAssync Method

```
public class MyAuthorization : ResourceAuthorizationManager
{
    public override Task<bool> CheckAccessAsync(ResourceAuthorizationContext context)
    {
        var resource = context.Resource.First().Value;
        var action =  context.Action.First().Value;

        // getting the roles that are connected to that resource and action
        // from the db. Context could of course be injected into the 
        // constructor of the class. In my code I assume that the table
        // thank links roles, resources and actions is called Roles ToActions
        using(var db = MyContext())
        var roles = db.RolesToActions   // Use your table name here
         .Where(r => r.Resource == resource && r.Action == action).ToList();

        foreach(var role in roles)
        {
            if(context.Principal.IsInRole(role.Name)
            {
                return Ok();
            }
        }

        return Nok();
    }
 }
```

}

So I hope this helps. If you prefer to implement your own attribute however, than the source code from the [ResourceAuthorization GitHub Repository](https://github.com/IdentityModel/Thinktecture.IdentityModel/blob/master/source/SystemWeb/Mvc/ResourceActionAuthorizeAttribute.cs) should be a good starting point